# How to prevent NVDA from reading "Div" as clickable?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, accessibility, nvda

Below is my sample code, when user clicks arrow-down NVDA is reading section as clickable.

```
<section>
<p>How would you like to pay?</p>
<form>
<input type="text"/>
<button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
</section>
```

I read somewhere that NVDA considers `<section>` as clickable, so I have tried changing `<section>` to `<div>` tag as shown below:

```
<div>
<p>How would you like to pay?</p>
<form>
<input type="text"/>
<button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
</div>
```

But the issue still exist.
It is reading:

> clickable
>   How would you like to pay?

Should not read `<div>` as clickable.

Comment: There's nothing here that would indicate that NVDA would announce this div or section as clickable, but here are some places to start looking: (1) does NVDA only start announcing clickable when you enter the div/section? (2) are there any javascript event handlers present on the page? (3) is there any HTML added to the DOM through scripting? If you can provide more code, you may get more helpful responses.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/5830 NVDA reads "Clickable" if there is mouse events associated with the dom element in question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set `tabindex=0` on the paragraph tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around. in your section tag add:

```
<section role="presentation">
```

read this:

> https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/examples/sensible-aria-usage/presentation/